# ivy - how to download all sources with just adding one line

Tags: ivy

I don't want to modify every single line to tell ivy to download ALL sources that it can of all jars.  Is there a way to add just one line or property to tell ivy to get all sources that it can for all jars/binaries that it gets so it's easier for our team to step through the code when we need to.

I guess I am looking for something like mavens "mvn dependency:sources" so I can just have a separate ant target or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a default configuration mapping in the **ivy.xml** file, as follows:

```
<configurations defaultconfmapping="compile->default;sources->sources">
    <conf name="compile" description="Compile classpath"/>
    <conf name="sources" description="Source jars"/>
</configurations>
```

This will create two groups of files. The compile classpath dependencies and the source jars.